# WPF firing events not existing on startup forms

Tags: c#, wpf, forms, events

I have some forms in my WPF Application. I specified my startup form in App.xaml lets say it **Form A**.

Somehow when application starts, my other forms' events firing like

- combobox selection changed
- checkbox checked changed

I'm only want to open **Form A** and don't want to other forms events firing. Is there any easy way to prevent those events from firing?

Ok this is my app.xaml

```html
<Application x:Class="MMS.UI.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MMS.UI"
             StartupUri="FormAcilis.xaml">
    <!--<Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Themes/Metro/Metro.MSControls.Core.Implicit.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Themes/Metro/Metro.MSControls.Toolkit.Implicit.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>-->
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Blue.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseLight.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/Resources/Icons.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <local:NullToBooleanConverter x:Key="ntb"/>
            <local:NullToVisibilityConverter x:Key="ntv"/>
            <local:NullToBooleanRevConverter x:Key="ntbr"/>
            <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="btv" />
            <local:BooleanToVisibilityRevConverter x:Key="btvr"/>
            <local:GroupsToTotalConverter x:Key="gtt"/>
            <local:GroupsToTotalConverter2 x:Key="gtt2"/>
            <local:DurumToBooleanConverter x:Key="dtb"/>
            <local:DurumToBooleanConverterRev x:Key="dtbr"/>
            <local:DosyalarToPathConverter x:Key="dtp"/>
            <Style x:Key="RightAligned" TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right"/>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

And this is the app.xaml.cs

```html
namespace MMS.UI
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for App.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            base.DispatcherUnhandledException += App_DispatcherUnhandledException;
        }

        void App_DispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
            var ex = new CustomException(e.Exception, "Providers, App.xaml()");
        }

        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("tr-TR"); ;
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("tr-TR"); ;

            FrameworkElement.LanguageProperty.OverrideMetadata(
              typeof(FrameworkElement),
              new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                    XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.IetfLanguageTag)));

            base.OnStartup(e);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not trying to open any other forms. But their events still firing.

Comment: If events from other windows fire, then you are opening other windows. Just don't do that.

Comment: You're obviously creating the other forms before they're shown, they're initializing, and that causes the events to fire. Nobody can tell you where in your code that's happening without seeing your code.

Comment: Thanks for comments. I edited my question and pasted the code.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i figured my bad and that was because a function which initialize the other forms like this :

```html
  List<MetroWindow> wndList = new List<MetroWindow>();
            try
            {
                Assembly uiProject = Assembly.Load("MMS"); 
                foreach (Type t in uiProject.GetTypes())
                {
                    if (t.BaseType == typeof(MetroWindow))
                    {
                        var emptyCtor = t.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);
                        if (emptyCtor != null)
                        {
                            MetroWindow f = (MetroWindow)emptyCtor.Invoke(new object[] { });
                            // t.FullName will help distinguish the unwanted entries and
                            // possibly later ignore them
                            wndList.Add(f);
                        }
                    }
                }
                return wndList;
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                // log exception
                return null;
            }
```

I was trying to get which windows my project have. Sorry for bad english. Your commends lighted to me for solution.